# golang zlib reader output not being copied over to stdout

Tags: go, zlib

I've modified the official documentation example for the zlib package to use an opened file rather than a set of hardcoded bytes (code below).

The code reads in the contents of a source text file and compresses it with the zlib package. I then try to read back the compressed file and print its decompressed contents into stdout.

The code doesn't error, but it also doesn't do what I expect it to do; which is to display the decompressed file contents into stdout.

> Also: is there another way of displaying this information, rather than using `io.Copy`?

```
    package main

    import (
        "compress/zlib"
        "io"
        "log"
        "os"
    )

    func main() {
        var err error

        // This defends against an error preventing `defer` from being called
        // As log.Fatal otherwise calls `os.Exit`
        defer func() {
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln("\nDeferred log: \n", err)
            }
        }()

        src, err := os.Open("source.txt")
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        defer src.Close()

        dest, err := os.Create("new.txt")
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        defer dest.Close()

        zdest := zlib.NewWriter(dest)
        defer zdest.Close()

        if _, err := io.Copy(zdest, src); err != nil {
            return
        }

        n, err := os.Open("new.txt")
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        r, err := zlib.NewReader(n)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        defer r.Close()
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, r)

        err = os.Remove("new.txt")
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `defer` func doesn't do anything, because you're shadowing the `err` variable on every new assignment. If you want a `defer` to run, return from a separate function, and call `log.Fatal` after the return statement.

As for why you're not seeing any output, it's because you're deferring all the Close calls. The `zlib.Writer` isn't flushed until after the function exits, and neither is the destination file. Call `Close()` explicitly where you need it.

```
zdest := zlib.NewWriter(dest)

if _, err := io.Copy(zdest, src); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
zdest.Close()
dest.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you messed up the code logic with all this `defer` stuff and your "trick" err checking.

Files are definitively written when flushed or closed. You just copy into new.txt without closing it **before** opening it to read it.

Defering the closing of the file is neat inside a function which has multiple exits: It makes sure the file is closed once the function is left. But your main requires the new.txt to be closed after the copy, before re-opening it. So don't defer the close here.

BTW: Your defense against log.Fatal terminating the code without calling your defers is, well, at least strange. The files are all put into some proper state by the OS, there is absolutely no need to complicate the stuff like this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the error from the second `Copy`:

```
2015/12/22 19:00:33 
Deferred log: 
 unexpected EOF
exit status 1
```

The thing is, you need to close `zdest` immediately after you've done writing. Close it after the first `Copy` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I would have suggested to use [io.MultiWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer).
In this way you read only once from src. Not much gain for small files but is faster for bigger files.

```
  w :=  io.MultiWriter(dest, os.Stdout)
```